# Linux python error when command in terminal not found

Tags: python, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 with kernel 4.13.0-39-generic. 
Every time I run a command in a terminal that is not valid or the program is not installed I get a stacktrace of a python error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

To answer the first question, yes gdbm is installed:

```
ii  libgdbm3:amd64                            1.8.3-13.1                                   amd64        GNU dbm database routines (runtime version)
ii  python-gdbm                              2.7.12-1~16.04                            amd64        GNU dbm database support for Python
ii  python3-gdbm:amd64                        3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2                     amd64       GNU dbm database support for Python 3.x
```

Comment: "a command in a terminal"? What do you expect to happen when you run an invalid command? Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: In any version of Linux (Ubuntu, Mint etc.) I never received a stacktrace when entering an unknown command. I always received a message like `<command>: Command not found` output

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1034266 (first result on google). Ah, now I get it: your problem is not at all about a Python script. ANY invalid shell command will cause this Python error.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error message you are missing the module 'gdbm' as it says here:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-gdbm
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The OP mentionned in his question, that the module `gdbm` is installed, but the error message is generated nevertheless. The issue must be somewhere else or you shoud explain your solution in more detail. Thanks.